# java equivalence of C++'s template <int val> class foo{ };

Tags: java, c++, templates, generics

I am new to Java, and am trying to do something similar to the following C++ template:

```
template <int value_>
class Foo{
    ....
};
```

where instantiations of with different `value_` behaves identically, but interaction between two instances with different `value_` would depend on `value1` and `value2`. In particular, causes compile-time failure if `value1 != value2` in some function.

One possible solution might be to store such value in the java class and throw run-time exception, but compile-time detection would be useful.

Comment: You will not be able to achieve compile-time detection with Java generics.

Comment: Thanks! Is there some other way to do some sort of compile-time checks without extra memory storage or code duplication?

Comment: Not that I know of. Java generics basically just hide that the Java bytecode they compile to use `Object` everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest thing java has to templates is [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/), but it's strictly limited to enforcing that the "right" types are used. Java doesn't have any value-based templating mechanism.

The best you could do is mock this behavior by creating a series of wrapper classes for the values you're interested in:

E.g., an interface:

```
public interface IntWrapper {
    int getValue();
}
```

and a couple of implementations:

```
public class OneWrapper implements IntWrapper {
    @Override
    public int getValue() {
        return 1;
    }
}

public class TwoWrapper implements IntWrapper {
    @Override
    public int getValue() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

And then use them to mock int values:

```
public class Foo <T extends IntWrapper> {
    public void interact (T other) {
        // ...
    }
}
```